# Lightning data Table onrowaction

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I am trying to use lighting Datatable with a button to edit record. I am trying at first to assure that when i click on the button catch the related record. But when i click edit button i got nothing.
My code is the following :

```
<aura:component  access="global" controller="test"  implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">

  <!-- attributes -->
  <aura:attribute name="RecordId" type="String" default="" access="global" />
  <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object[]"/>
  <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>

  <!-- handlers-->
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>


  <div class="slds-p-top_xx-large slds-p-bottom_xx-large slds-text-heading_large">Composants à vérifier</div>
  <lightning:datatable
                keyField="id"
                data="{! v.data }"
                columns="{! v.columns }"
                hideCheckboxColumn="false"
                onrowaction="{!c.editRow}"/>

</aura:component>
```

```
({
  init: function (cmp, event, helper) {

    cmp.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'N° de ligne de vérification', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Objets', fieldName: 'objet__c', type: 'text'},
        {label: ' Charge Name', fieldName: 'ChargeName__c', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Fonctionnel', fieldName: 'Functional__c', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Présent', fieldName: 'Present__c', type: 'text'},
        {type:  'button',typeAttributes:{
          iconName: 'utility:edit',
          label: 'Edit', 
          name: 'editRecord', 
          title: 'editTitle', 
          disabled: false, 
          value: 'test'
          }
        }
    ]);
    let action = cmp.get("c.getrelatedComponentChecking");
    action.setParams({ 
        taskId : cmp.get("v.RecordId")
    });
    console.log('taskId='+cmp.get("v.RecordId"));
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      console.log('state='+state);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
          console.log('data='+response.getReturnValue());
          cmp.set("v.data", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
  editRow: function (cmp,event,helper){
    console.log("###Avant");
    var recId = event.getParam('row').Id;
    console.log('###########');
    console.log('###Id='+recId);
  } 
});
```

Comment: did `editRow` function fired?

Comment: i just tested your code, it's working fine and got Id of record, i haven't get any issue.

Comment: Does your `v.data` consist of `Id` field? The statement `var recId = event.getParam('row').Id;` will only work if the `v.data` has an `Id` value set.

Comment: No, when i click nothing happen